# Invoke The stream does not support reading

Tags: c#, exception, networkstream, notsupportedexception

I have a c# network application where alot of anonymous users connect to (game service).

Now I check the logs and occasionally I see this exception:

```
[10:30:18.21352] System.Int32 Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32): The stream does not support reading.
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at BusinessLayer.Listener.ListenerWorker.ProcessClient(Object obj) in File.cs:line 141
```

This error comes from a NetworkStream object, now I am trying to reproduce the problem, but how? How can I get this exception?

I tried disconnecting myself, but that just gives a timeout, tried other things, but cannot get it to work.

Maybe somebody has an idea?

Contents of the file is:

```
private static void ProcessClient(
    Object obj)
{
    ISession session = (ISession)obj;
    NetworkStream networkStream = null;

    try
    {
        DebugUtility.SetThreadName("Worker: {0}", session.Name);
        networkStream = session.TcpClient.GetStream();
        networkStream.ReadTimeout = Config.ReadTimeout;

        // Loop received packets (blocks untill next packet)
        Int32 packetSize;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[session.PacketSize];
        while ((packetSize = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            // Get String from packet  bytes
            String packet = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, packetSize);

            // Check if packet has data
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(packet))
                continue;

            // Log biggest received package
            DebugUtility.CheckMaxPacketSize(session.Name, packet.Length);

            // Handle packet (in new thread)
            Logger.DebugLog("Received: {0}", packet);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(session.HandlePacket, packet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogException(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (networkStream != null)
            networkStream.Close();

        if (session != null)
            session.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is line 141 in `File.cs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What arguments are you passing in the

```
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

method. Are you using **any** of  **NetworkStream.Length** or **NetworkStream.Position** properties.

i.e is it somthing like (not exactly)

```
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(buffer, stream.Position, stream.Length)
```

then as explained in MSDN documentation **use of** [`NetworkStream.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.length.aspx) and [`NetworkStream.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.position.aspx) properties **will always throw** a `NotSupportedException` as its not currently Supported.

Comment: @Rogier21 can you show us what arguments are you passing in the Read method

Comment: I added the sourcefile, should be self explanatory, but the exception is only raised on rare conditions, rare enough that I can't find out how, so not on every call.